# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have looked through the other questions but none of the answers worked for me.

The error I'm getting when trying to inflate the RecyclerView is:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

This is an Example-Item for the ArrayList I am trying to inflate into my RecyclerView:

```
//Chord Obj: Chord(int images[], String name, Int sound) 

chords.add(new Chord(new int[]{
            R.drawable.do_maggiore, R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt1, R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt2,
            R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt3, R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt4, R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt5,
            R.drawable.do_maggiore_alt6}, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.c), R.raw.do_maggiore));
```

This is my `List_Adapter.java`:

```
public class List_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<List_adapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Chord> list;
Context c;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private ImageView image;

    private MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chord_image);
    }
}

public List_adapter(Context c, ArrayList<Chord> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.c = c;
}

@Override public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int pos) {
    Chord chord = list.get(pos);
    holder.name.setText(chord.getName());
    holder.image.setImageResource(chord.getImages()[0]);
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {return list.size();}
}
```

This is where I get the list and inflate it into my `Main_Activity.onCreate()`:

```
 /* gets the list */
    chords = new ArrayList<>();
    ChordsList list = new ChordsList();
    list.createList();
    chords = list.getList();

    /* puts the list into the recyclerView */
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chords_recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Main_list_activity.this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final List_adapter adapter = new List_adapter(this, chords);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and finally, this is my xml:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chords_recycler"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
...
```

This is what I have tried so far:

- Checked if RecyclerView was somehow shrinked or hidden. It's not.
- Added and removed several Elements from my list. Nothing changed.
- Tried to set the Recycler to an empty adapter first. no luck either.
- debugged and checked if the list was null when inflated. It is not.

Don't really know what else I could do. I'd appreciate some help.

**EDIT:**

I do not really know if it helpful but I used the Navigation Drawer Preset when creating my project and I'm adding this code in a class I created and set the layout to `R.layout.content_drawer`.

Furthermore when debugging I don't get any result from the debugger here is an Image:

[image: debug_image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it. The problem was quite obvious actually but I did not fully understand it when writing the question.

I simply created another activity and set the layout to be the content_drawer. This is wrong because all the code needs to be put in the `Drawer.class` (If you are using the Navigation Drawer preset in Android Studio).

This is why the debugger showed nothing, because it never got to that class at all. And because that code was never even run, of course it could not display anything.

Thanks for the answers I got.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your **RecyclerView** height to **"match_parent"** and then see the output whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried that but had no luck

Comment: can you please check that the recyclerview is not with the scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

use following when you set adapter:-

```
List_adapter adapter = new List_adapter(this, chords);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of

```
final List_adapter adapter = new List_adapter(this, chords);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this one did not work too

Comment: can you make sure that you are adding right data in array list as you want to set in the adapter..

Comment: What do you mean? you can see the code above. to me it looks fine the Chord object has got an Array of images, a name String and an audio file. And this is everything I defined in the Chord model class

Comment: I have solved your issue.. i am adding code with new answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not showing because you are trying to inflate the RecyclerView inside **onCreate** method. Please move your RecyclerView code to **onResume** method of your activity.

```
 /* gets the list */
    chords = new ArrayList<>();
    ChordsList list = new ChordsList();
    list.createList();
    chords = list.getList();

    /* puts the list into the recyclerView */
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chords_recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Main_list_activity.this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final List_adapter adapter = new List_adapter(this, chords);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried. Even if I have the code in onResume() the List is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Insert following in your activity :

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Chord> chords;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        setAdapter();
    }
private void setAdapter() {
     chords = new ArrayList<>();

    chords.add(new Chord(new int[]{
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher},"Name", R.raw.audio_in_raw));


    List_adapter adapter = new List_adapter(chords, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

add following in your adapter:

```
public class List_adapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<List_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Chord> chord;
Context context;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvText;
    ImageView ivImage;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ivImage= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        tvText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    }
}


public List_adapter(List<Chord> chord,  Context context) {
    this.chord = chord;
    this.context =  context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.customadapter_chords, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.tvText.setText(chord.get(position).getName());
    holder.ivImage.setImageResource(chord.get(position).getImages()[0]);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chord.size();
}
```

}

and add following in adapter :-

```
public class Chord {
int images[];
String name;
int sound;

public Chord(int[] images, String name, int sound) {
    this.images = images;
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;

}

public int[] getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(int[] images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getSound() {
    return sound;
}

public void setSound(int sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
}
}
```

and xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:weightSum="10"

>
<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ImageView>

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: if you still facing problem then  let me know

Comment: thanks again for the help man. basically it's the xml that has changed. Actually I have a row.xml that looks like the one you wrote, and that's where the adapter puts the images and strings and that row is infated into the Recycler. Please have a look at the edited question have you got any Idea why the debugger is empty?

Comment: there are little bit changes in adapter and model classes also..... you can copy and paste in your code..then you will get the difference